# Conditional Expectation: How to Intergrate indicator function multiplied by the joint denisity?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-expectation

I am currently reading "*Measure, Integral and Probability*" by Capinski, Marek (see p179). It includes some motivation for the definition of the conditional expectation. For example, given two random variables $X,Y$ with joint density $f_{(X,Y)}$ (and so the marginal and conditional densities), we want to show that for any set $A \subset \Omega, A=X^{-1}(B), B$ Borel, that $$\int_A\mathbb{E}(Y|X)dP= \int_A \mathbb{E}(Y)dP.$$
This is one of the defining condition of an conditional expectation.
The book shows the following calculation,
\begin{align}
\int_A\mathbb{E}(Y|X)dP &= \int_\Omega 1_B(X)\mathbb{E}(Y|X)dP\\
&= \int_\Omega 1_B(X(\omega))\left(\int_\mathbb{R}yf_{Y|X}(y|X(\omega))dy\right)dP(\omega)\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R}1_B(x)yf_{(Y|X)}(y|x)dy f_X(x)dx\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R}1_B(x)yf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy\\
&= \int_\Omega 1_A(X)YdP\\
&= \int_A YdP.
\end{align}
What I don't understand is the second to last equality immediately above, i.e. 
$$ \int_\mathbb{R} y \int_\mathbb{R}1_B(x)f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy = \int_\Omega 1_A(X)YdP .$$
I think it is a typo since $X\in \mathbb{R}$ and $A \subset \Omega$ --- however, I cant figure the correction either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a typo, the author certainly intended to write $\int_\Omega 1_B(X)YdP $.

Indeed $$\int_\mathbb{R} \int_\mathbb{R}1_B(x)yf_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy = \int 1_B(x)y dP_{(X,Y)}(x,y) = \int 1_B(X)YdP$$

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you. Could you also clarify the last equality in that case
$$\int_\Omega 1_B(X)YdP_{(X,Y)} = \int_\Omega 1_A Y dP_{Y} = \int_A YdP_Y?$$
My confusion is how the measure goes from $P_{(X,Y)}$ to $P_{(Y)}$, if that is even correct?

Comment: $\int_\Omega 1_B(X)YdP_{(X,Y)} = \int_\Omega 1_A Y dP_{Y}$ need not hold.

Comment: I mean how is $\int 1_B(X)YdP = \int_A Y dP$ --- specifically in regards to the measure $P$ is it the joint or the marginal distribution (the notation isn't very good for this part of the book)? Surely, there must be some change in the measure?

Comment: Simply note that for all $w$, $1_B(X(w)) = 1_A(w)$.

Comment: In $\int 1_B(X)YdP$ and $\int 1_A YdP$, $P$ is the measure on the original measure space, usually introduced as $(\Omega,\Sigma, P)$.